# MySQL query to find most sold products within a time period

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, group-by

I have two tables. Here are some fields that will be used in query.

```
tgc_sales (code,sale_date_time, order_status)

tgc_sales_items (sales_code, quantity, product_name, product_code)
```

What I want is to get the most sold products within a specific period of time (say a week, a month etc).

What I tried so far:

```
SELECT SUM(tsi.quantity) AS quantity, tsi.product_name AS product_name
FROM tgc_sales_items tsi 
JOIN tgc_sales ts ON ts.code = tsi.sales_code
WHERE DATE(ts.sale_date_time)>='2014-05-01'
    AND ts.order_status='Completed' 
GROUP BY tsi.product_code
ORDER BY quantity DESC LIMIT 10
```

Obviously, the query is wrong and it is giving me unexpected result. When I ignore the JOIN and WHERE clause it shows me the most sold products but I need it for when the sales was made in a specific period and I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: What is the type of `sales_date_time`?  Please edit the question with some sample values.

Comment: if you remove the aggregate SUM() do you get the correct quantity values in relation to the items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query looks right, assuming that `code` is a unique (or primary) key on the `tgc_sales` table, and `sales_code` is a foreign key reference to that column.

The use of the `DATE()` function seems a bit odd.

If the `sales_date_time` column has a datatype of DATE, DATETIME, or TIMESTAMP, then the `DATE()` function isn't needed, and it's not desirable because it disables MySQL's ability to use an index range scan to satisfy the predicate.

If the `sales_date_time` is character, and your intent is to convert the character into a DATE, you'd use the `STR_TO_DATE()` function. But you don't really want to store `sales_date_time` as a character string.

If that's a DATETIME column, you'd do something like this:

```
WHERE ts.sale_date_time >= '2014-05-01'
  AND ts.sale_date_time <  '2014-06-01'
```

If it's a character column in a non-canonical format (e.g. 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss'), then you could do something like:

```
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(ts.sale_date_time,'%m/%d/%Y %h:%i:%s') >= '2014-05-01'
  AND STR_TO_DATE(ts.sale_date_time,'%m/%d/%Y %h:%i:%s') <  '2014-06-01'
```

(But you don't really want to store a date time value in a character string; you want to use one of the MySQL datatypes like DATETIME.)

If you're storing a unix-style timestamp "seconds since the beginning of an era", then you'd want to do the comparison against the native column values. You could do something like this:

```
WHERE ts.sale_date_time >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-05-01')
  AND ts.sale_date_time <  UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-06-01')
```

...though you'd really prefer to use the same library used to do the conversion when the values were stored, and do the query more like this:

```
WHERE ts.sale_date_time >= 1398902400
  AND ts.sale_date_time <  1401580800
```

Comment: Hi Spencer, Thanks. Once you said, the query looks ok assuming the primary and foreign key constraint, I did few testing and found out there were some bad data in the tables which meant I had duplicates where it should have been unique. I removed all records and all works fine. Thanks for pointing me the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Your group by seems suspicious. It includes product_code column which is not in the select clause.

Comment: Tarik, even if I use group by product_name, it still shows the same result set. The product_name for a specific product_code is same. Sorry for the confusion.